# Sed not working correctly

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I'm trying to insert some lines into a directive in the Apache conf file, so that this is the final output:

```
<Directory />
Order deny,allow    
Deny from all
Options None
AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

I tried just to verify that it works:

```
http_file=/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
sed -n "<Directory /> a\Deny from all" $http_file
```

But it gives this error: `sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: '<'`.

So I escaped the special characters and tried this:

`sed -n "/\<Directory \/\>/ a\Deny from all" $http_file`

But it still doesn't work.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this sed:

```
sed -n '/<Directory *\/>/ a\
Deny from all' "$http_file"
```

Comment: Thanks man, that did the trick. Can you explain why asterisk works?

Comment: `*` in regex is for zero or more occurrences. Since multiple spaced before `/>` are optional I used ` *` to match 0 or more spaces.

Comment: I understand that, my question is why didn't you have to escape the special characters < / and > ?

Comment: I have escaped `/` but `<` and `>` are not special hence no escaping needed.